# RDS Database storage runs out of space

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just upgraded my RDS Storage from 10GB to 20GB and after a couple of days RDS says Storage full again.

Running this query in MySQL workbench against the same DB says the DB size is 43MB

```
SELECT table_schema "database_name", 
sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 
1024 "Data Base Size in MB", 
sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

So is there something going on with the logs that MySQL creates or the backups etc that might fill up my storage space on the production servers.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Its probably mysql.slow_log table which takes so much space.
You can remove slow logs by executing following sql:

```
CALL mysql.rds_rotate_slow_log
```

Comment: However, Amazon claims that ["The MySQL slow query log, error log, and the general log file sizes are constrained to no more than 2 percent of the allocated storage space for a DB instance."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html) - so how could the log files size of a 43MB db reach 20GB?...

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of logs in mysql.
Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html.
But I advice to look at slow query logs. If you have a lot of slow queries your log will increase fast.
Also check option --log-queries-not-using-indexes. Maybe you log all your queries without indexes.

Comment: How do I access these logs and delete them to recover space? and by the way we are on MySQL 5.1.57, slow query logs are from 5.1.6 onwards.

Comment: I see that innodb_log_file_size = 134217728 and max_binlog_size = 134217728 can that be the problem?

Comment: It seems that this one is cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your System tablespace might be consuming the space.

You can check it using the query below:

```
select TABLESPACE_NAME,FILE_NAME,FREE_EXTENTS,TOTAL_EXTENTS,EXTENT_SIZE
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.files 
where TABLESPACE_NAME in ('innodb_system','innodb_temporary');
```

Try to reboot your database. It should solve the problem.